# Error messages in js file or inside html for i18n

Tags: javascript, internationalization

In my company we are embedding the error messages in the js files, e.g.

```
const INVALID_PASS = "The password was not valid";
const INVALID_DATE_FORMAT = "The given date format was not valid (expeted yyyy/MM/dd";
```

to be used as text of specific error boxes, e.g.

```
const INVALID_INPUT = "Input was not correct";

function onFailCallback(jXHR){
  if(jqXHR.status === 400) {
    $('#error-message').text(INVALID_INPUT);
  }
}
```

Now, I'm wondering if this is the best approach. For instance we are going to introduce i18n. So far we are using the server application to replace messages in internationalization. Should we hard-code the messages in the html page and read them from there?

Comment: You could use something like http://i18next.com for translation on clientside. But as all your translations currently done on your server i wouldn't change that and stay by that.

Comment: In this simple use case, it's better to keep your translations on the server and then hard-code them to HTML page. Once you get to the point, where you actually need an i18n library on the frontend (e.g: you'll need pluralization, date/number formatting, etc) then take a look at [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) - i18n library for JS.